# Is there a fixed real number for which $\displaystyle\zeta(x)$ is integer?

Tags: riemann-zeta, integers

it is known that if  $x$ is integer and $x=-2n$ with $n >0 $ ,$\zeta(x)=0$ and is integer , here **My question** is to ask if there is a fixed real number for which $\zeta(x)$ is integer ?

> **Note:** If there is no real number how I disproof the titled question ?

Comment: For $x\geq 1.729$ we have $1 < \zeta(x) < 2$ so there are no solutions here. As $x\to 1^+$ we have $\zeta(x)\to \infty$ monotonically so there is one solution to $\zeta(x) = n$ for $x>1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Monotone and continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that $\zeta(x)$ is continuous for all $x>1$.  Second, $\zeta(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to1^+$ and $\zeta(2)<2$.

Thus, it follows by the intermediate value theorem, $\zeta(x)$ attains all integers greater than or equal to $2$.

Similarly argument for $x\in[-2,1)$ shows $\zeta(x)$ will take all negative integers including zero.

Comment: And the functional equation shows it takes all the integer values on $(-\infty,-a]$

Comment: another interesting theorem is that $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)-b}$ has at least one pole on $Re(s) > 1$ for every $b \in \mathbb{C}$, except at most one exception. The prime number theorem shows this exceptional value of $b$ is $0$. The 1st step is [this theorem](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1353556,1353836#msg-1353836) in Titchmarsh's book.

Comment: We can also approximate the solutions quite well: since $\zeta(s) \sim \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma$ for $s\to 1$ we have $\zeta(x) = n$ when $x\simeq 1 + \frac{1}{n - \gamma}$. For example for $n=10$ this approximation gives $x \simeq 1.10613$ while the true solution is $x= 1.10621$.

Comment: @Winther better yet, the relationship to the dirichlet eta function.